# Understanding the "daily" and "weekly" scopes in Unity.Social & Apple GameCenter Leaderboards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

Unity's `Social.TimeScope` documentation says:

> TimeScope.Today: Only return scores from today
>   https://docs.unity3d.com/352/Documentation/ScriptReference/TimeScope.Today.html

However, Apple's native Swift documentation says:

> case today: Each player is restricted to scores recorded in the past 24 hours.
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkleaderboardtimescope

So, when using `Unity.Social.TimeScope` to fetch "daily" scores from Apple's GameCenter, which of the following are returned:

1. Scores from today's date (And if so, in which timezone?).
2. Scores from the past 24 hours, regardless of dates.

The same goes for the "weekly" time scopes: what does "the last week" mean here?

1. In the scope of the "current" week, i.e. since Sunday?
2. In the scope of the last 168 hours (7*24), regardless of the current day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I ran a little "expirement" using `TimeScope. Today` for `LoadScores`and figured it out myself:

- I posted a highscore at 17:00.
- *The next day* I posted a lower score at 10:00, and still saw the higher score returned when I used `LoadScores`.
- I posted the lower score again at 18:00, which was more than 24 hours after the higher score was posted, and this time the lower score was the one that was returned by `LoadScores`.

**Conclusion:** `Social.TimeScope.Daily` == Scores from the past 24 hours, regardless of dates.

I am assuming the same logic goes for `Weekly`: hours instead of dates.